Who is this Rishabha mentioned at the end of Ramyana?
This excerpt from Uttara Khanda of Ramayana mentiones that someone named Rishabha will civizilite Ayodhya again, long after the end of Rama Avatar:-

The enchanting City of Ayodhya, having remained deserted for countless years, will be re-peopled by a Prince named Rishabha.

Who is this Rishabha and Is any detail about him?

It's most likely the Jain Tirthankara Rishabhadeva who according to Hinduism is an avatar of Vishnu -

The region of Himahvaya was ruled by the great Nabhi. With his queen,
Merudevī, he had a brilliant son, Rsabha. Rsabha himself had a hundred
sons, of whom Bharata was the eldest. Having ruled wisely and
performed varied sacrifices, King Rsabha placed his son heroic Bharata
upon the throne, then that fortunate man retired to the ashram of
Pulaha to undertake austerities. Following the prescription for those
who retire to the forest, that resolute king duly performed
austerities and instituted sacrifices.Wasted by his practices, he grew
thin, his veins distended. Naked Rsabha placed a pebble in his mouth
and took the path of heroes. Because this region was given to Bharata
by his father when he retired to the forest, it’s known throughout the
threefold worlds as Bhārata.


Chapter 4, 5th Skandha, Srimad Bhagavatam.

According to Jain texts, his capital was Ayodhya.

So, it is implies that Rshabha Avatar is took place after Rama.

@Boovanaes - Yes.
